# How can I find the average of the 2 matrix?

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

Im am writitng a Javascript and need help....

```js
var h, A, B, C, D, Answer;
h = [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4], [0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1]]

A = h[0][0]*h[1][0]
B = h[0][1]*h[1][1]
C = h[0][2]*h[1][2]
D = h[0][3]*h[1][3]
Answer = (A+B+C+D)/4
document.write (Answer);
```

I would like to find the average of matrix as shown below? I would like my program to find the average from sample 1 and sample 2. Example: sample 1 has the following matrix: [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4], and sample 2 has the following [0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1].
My solution will be: {0.1*0.4 + 0.2*0.3 + 0.3*0.2 + 0.4*0.1}/4 = 0.05

How can i construct my code using for loops?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array.reduce() function.

```js
var h, Answer;
h = [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4], [0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1]];
Answer = h[0].reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array) {
  return previousValue + currentValue*h[1][index]/array.length;
},0);
alert(Answer);
```

More details: [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

With loops

```js
var h, Answer;
h = [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4], [0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1]];
var length = h[0].length;
Answer=0;
for (var i=0; i<length; i++){
    Answer += (h[0][i]*h[1][i])/length;
}
alert(Answer);
```

Comment: hmmmm, what is the 0 at the end doing? Can you please guide me to do it using for loops?

Comment: The second example includes the loop... First example is another way of doing it. The 0 in the first example is the initial value of the previousValue argument. You have to go through documentation to understand it..

Comment: Solution 1 is more elegant. @Algerino, if you want to do JavaScript way or functional way then that would be the way to go.